# Projection of point cloud on 2D image based on mesh information

Tags: python, render, mesh, point-clouds

I have a point cloud and meshes (vertices=points of the point cloud).
I want to project the point cloud with a certain virtual camera.
Here, since the point cloud is sparse, the rendered result includes the points which should be occluded by foreground objects.

To resolve this issue, I want to use mesh information to identify which points should be occluded.
Is there any smart way to do this in python?

Kind advice will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What kind of advice you expect ? Because this kind of rendering is not trivial. Do you want to try to use a mesh renderer already implemented or is your goal to start the implementation of your own renderer ?

Comment: I think I have to clarify my goal in more detail. Sorry for my ambiguous question. 

First of all, how the mesh renderer rejects the occluded surfaces from rendering? Moreover, since the entity that I want to project is a point cloud (not meshes), I also want to know how can I utilize the occlusion-rejection strategy of mesh rendering for point cloud projection. 
Rather than implementing my own renderer, it would be much better if I can use one already implemented.

Comment: For the theory you can start with wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden-surface_determination
If you need a renderer I once used Ogre3D for a small AR android application, it seems to exist also in Python. But you should take the time to search which framework would be the best for your project (pick one with examples that are close of what you are trying to achieve). The keywords for your research are "3D engine python".

Comment: Thanks, Lucas. Your advice helps me a lot. I searched and studied about rendering pipeline for a few hours, and I solved it!

Answer (score 2):

After hours of searching, I conclude that I have to re-implement a novel rendering pipeline to achieve my goal.

So, instead of this, I use a mesh-based renderer to render a depth map.
And then I simply project the points of the point cloud with a projection matrix.
Here, I use the depth map to check whether the point fits with the depth or not.
If the projected point is the one that should be occluded, then the depth of the point would be larger than the depth map value at the corresponding pixel.
So, such points should be ignored while rendering.

I know that this is a less elegant and inefficient trick but anyway it works very well :)